# How to filter rows in agGrid based on display value?

Tags: angular, filtering, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have agGrid which contains column that has used refData property. It is displaying as "Yes" or "No" but has underlying value as "1" or "0". I want to filter the column by data but it is not giving any result when filter by "Yes" or "No". However filter starts working when I put underlying data i.e. 1 or 0.

**HTML File**

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-balham" 
            [rowData]="categoryRowData" [columnDefs]="categoryColDef" [domLayout]="domLayout"
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
       </ag-grid-angular>
```

**TS File**

```
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit{
    private domLayout;
    private objCategoryEditor = {};
    categoryColDef ;

    constructor()
    {
        this.getCategoryMapping();
        this.createCategoryColDefinition();
    }

    ngOnInit() {        
        this.domLayout = "autoHeight";
    }

    onGridReady(params: any) {            
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        params.api.resetRowHeights();                                     
    }

    createCategoryColDefinition() {
        this.categoryColDef = [            
        {
            headerName: 'Is Subcategory', field: 'IsSubcategoryText', resizable: true,filter:true,
            editable: function (params: any) {
                return true;
            },
            cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: this.extractValues(this.objCategoryEditor),
            },
            refData: this.objCategoryEditor,            
        }
    ]}

    getCategoryMapping()
    {
        this.objCategoryEditor["0"] = "No";
        this.objCategoryEditor["1"] = "Yes";    
        this.createCategoryColDefinition();                     
    }

    extractValues(mappings) {    
        return Object.keys(mappings);            
    }
}
```

When filter by "No" then it is returning no rows:-

[image]

When filter by 0 then it is returning rows:-

[image]

How to customize the filtering so that it start returning rows when filter by "Yes" or "No"? 
Please help on this.

Comment: I think it cannot be achieved using agGrid-community version. It would be achieved via agSetColumnFilter which is part of agGrid-Enterprise and chargeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a `filterValueGetter` in column definition something like this -

```
 filterValueGetter: this.customfilterValueGetter
```

here is a simple implementation of `customfilterValueGetter`

```
 customfilterValueGetter(params) {
    if(params.data) {
      return this.objCategoryEditor[params.data.IsSubcategoryText];
    }
 }
```

As per docs -

> **filterValueGetter(params)**
>    Function or expression. Gets the value for filtering purposes.

Plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/s0c84FHi80CPt7dt). Checkout the **Retail Price** column

Comment: Thanks alot. I was looking for property "filterValueGetter". Your answer helped me.

Comment: Thanks!! Worked well in my case especially since the documentation around this method is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an object key with 0 and 1 use yes and No properties itself like below, which will help you to solve this issue

```
   getCategoryMapping()
    {
        this.objCategoryEditor["No"] = "No";
        this.objCategoryEditor["Yes"] = "Yes";    
        this.createCategoryColDefinition();                     
    }
```

Comment: No I cant. These values are coming from DB. Even for other grids some Guids are also coming and bind to agGrid.